# Raycasting vs OpenGL-ES 2.0 - is there a noticeable difference for Doom like game on Android?

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, raycasting

It's my first question, I searched on google as always, round two was searching directly on SO, but still I couldn't get the exact answer.

I'm going to write 3D graphics engine for games I want to make in the future for Android platform. I played Doom recently on my mobile, on break in high-school, and when I lifted my head after being killed by Baron of Hell I saw more that twenty people struggling to see me playing, followed by loud "AAAAAAAW!" when they saw me dead. My jaw went down to the floor. None of them suspected that it was game from 1993.

But let's get back to the point. If you wanted to write "find it by yourself" you can stop typing now. I can't check this on my own, for different reasons. At first I own only one mid-cost device (HTC Wildfire) I can test my engine on. The second and more important reason is time. I don't have time to write whole OpenGL-ES 2.0 graphics engine and realize that my Wildfire can't even run it. Or it gets around 1FPS when walking.

For raycasting to be more realistic it needs few calculations, which are not important for me in OpenGL because I just set vertices & indices and it goes. I love the way that Doom levels are designed but I wanted to add ability to move your head up and down (rotation on X-axis) to look around and shoot more precisely, and the complexity of calculations in raycasting are growing (not for me, for CPU). I know Wildfire doesn't have any GPU and anything based on OGL (even 2D) is lagging as hell even if I overclock my CPU to @748 with PERFORMANCE governor (it turns off on higher values, and I got to move it from my Casemate to stop it from overheating). But Doom is running perfectly without any lag even if I underclock it to @448. Is this only because of lo-res textures and non-complex levels or because of raycasting?

And please don't flame for going back to such old thing like raycasting engine. Actual mobile devices, or smartphones - call them like you want - that doesn't cost $1k are in stage that computers was 18 (Doom release) years ago. There will always be a group of such devices. And even if I don't make my billion on this - I will have something to play on travel.

I've got some pretty nice ideas for games like this, and I want to hit the low cost devices as they don't have anything more spectacular than simple logic games. As this is my first question please correct anything I wrote wrong, poorly or just bad - I'll rewrite it.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know - great first post!  The simple answer is likely that the developers for the Doom game you were playing wrote their own native engine that does not do many of the things that OGLes2.0 does.  Therefore, it is much less expensive computationally to draw these things on the screen.  Try checking out some simpler engines before you attempt anything 3D.  I'm currently working with AndEngine, an open source 2D OpenGL engine for Android, and it works pretty well.  I'd suggest you give it a shot and see if you like it

Comment: Raycasting is pretty complex, although its a nice idea I personally dont think your going to need it. If you use OpenGL ES correctly will achieve a consistent frame rate without the need for these optimisations. I know this is a vague post but I have never needed anything else other than the OpenGL methods for Android developing

Comment: Pheonixblade9 Well yeah - AndEngine is pretty good and I use it for my another project (ActionRPG in Diablo style), but I want to develop this FPS at the same time.

Chris I know it's complex, but creating nice looking game for device like Wildfire is complex too.

Comment: Hi, there is a reason why you can't lift your head up in Doom. Not that it's creators were that stupid or didn't think of such feature, it presents an important optimization for rendering. This is all rather complex and is related to perspective correction. The code for drawing vertical polygons is simpler and faster, and that was the limit at the time the game was created. Today, phone apps are fillrate limited just as well - so there is a question whether you can actually improve the game. Also, Doom uses BSP trees to calculate wall visibility, which is both hard to implement and neccessary.

Comment: So if you're saying you don't have a lot of time, AND unable to use OpenGL for rendering, you better pass on this.

Comment: I said I don't have time to waste it on writing engine only to realise that it won't run. There is a difference between my text and your interpretation. Also, BSP trees are not so complicated, there is even illustrated instruction on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning).